# Error downloading statsmodel

Tags: openssl, conda

I am trying to download statsmodels using anaconda prompt.  I tried the command `conda install -c conda-forge statsmodels` and got the following error.

[image: screenshot]

Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: This looks like a conda, openssl problem and not one with statsmodels.

Comment: Thanks, any advice on resolving a conda openssl problem?

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Paste the text directly to your question and apply code formatting (the `{}` icon).